# Is it possible for a plane to accelerate easily from 30 to 45 mph in flight while it struggles to reach 30 mph (the engine runs at constant power)?

Tags: aviation-history, drag, airspeed

In two letters sent to Dr. G. A. Spratt (an aviation enthusiast), Wilbur Wright reported the progress he and his brother had made, up to September 10, 1904, regarding Flyer II, a plane powered by a 16-17 hp engine. (The pilot had no means to control the motor in flight. He could just stop it, in which case the machine landed.)

The plane needed an airspeed of about 30 mph to fly well. The machine lifted at 23-24 mph (airspeed) but it always fell unless the airspeed reached 25 mph. Between 25 and 30 mph it struggled to keep flying but if somehow reached 30 mph then it accelerated without problem, by itself, to 45 mph.

Assuming the aerodynamic resistance was $$\text{Drag} = kV^2$$
where k is a constant and V was the airspeed, it results that the plane needed the power $$P = \text{Drag} \times V = kV^3$$ to fly at a constant speed, V, and in consequence the necessary power for 45 mph would have been **$(45/30)^3 = 3.375$ times greater** than that required for flying at 30 mph. In other words, the apparatus would have needed at least 3.375 x 16 hp = 54 hp to reach 45 mph. The difference in power is enormous.

Between 30 and 45 mph the drag should have followed a significantly different law from $\text{Drag} = kV^2$. What would that law be?

1904-08-16, Wilbur Wright, “Letter to G. A. Spratt”, Dayton, August 16, 1904.

> Dear Dr. Spratt, ...
> Up to Aug. 1st we had made but fourteen trials;
> since then we have made seventeen more. So far our longest flight is
> only 1304 ft. in 39-1/2 seconds, which though farther over the ground
> than our longest flight at Kitty Hawk is not its equal in duration of
> time or distance through the air. We are however working under much
> less favorable conditions so far as grounds and atmospheric conditions
> are concerned. We have found difficulty in getting satisfactory starts
> owing to the fact that the winds are usually very light by spells, and
> **the new machine** requires a higher relative speed for starting than the
> old one. It **lifts at a speed of 23 or 24 miles an hour but the angle
> is so great that the resistance exceeds the thrust and the machine
> soon stalls. Between 25 and 30 miles it is a case of nip and tuck
> between them; but after the relative speed reaches 30 miles, the
> thrust exceeds the resistance and the speed accelerates till a
> velocity of forty five or fifty miles is reached.** So far the highest
> speed attained is forty five miles, but it may exceed this when we get
> to making longer flights. We are proceeding very cautiously; and do
> not intend to attempt anything spectacular until we know that it is
> safe, and we know all of the machines peculiar tricks. ... Yours
> truly, Wilbur Wright.

1904-09-10, Wilbur Wright, “Letter to G. A. Spratt”, Dayton, September 10, 1904.

> Dear Dr. Spratt, ...
> We have made forty five starts with our 1904 Flyer. Unless the
> relative speed at starting is 27 miles in a calm and two or three
> miles more than that in a wind, the machine will gradually slow down
> till unable to fly. **After the relative speed passes thirty miles the
> velocity accelerates till a relative speed of 45 to fifty miles is
> reached.** We found it difficult in practice to get a speed down the
> track greater than 20 miles an hour, so that **unless we had a wind of
> about 10 miles we were not sure of being able to fly for a lull in the
> wind would let us drop below the real flying limit**. As we were not
> ready to turn our backs to such a wind on account of the enormous
> speed in landing when going with the wind our flights have been
> confined to the length of our pasture field. We have made a number of
> flights between 1250 and 1450 ft long. **We have now finished a starting
> apparatus which gives a speed at start of 27 miles an hour in a dead
> calm, and expect shortly to begin circling**. With longer flights and
> less hauling the machine back, we hope to get more practice than
> heretofore.  With kind regards, Yours truly, Wilbur Wright.

This is just an illustration that shows Flyer I and II. It has nothing to do with the two letters quoted above.

[image: The 1904 Wright Flyer II was almost identical to the 1903 Flyer I, as you can see by comparing these two photos.]
[The 1904 Wright Flyer II was almost identical to the 1903 Flyer, as you can see by comparing these two photos](http://www.wright-brothers.org/Information_Desk/Just_the_Facts/Airplanes/Flyer_II.htm). The picture with Flyer I (1903) was first published in *“The Wright Brothers’ Aeroplane”, The Century Magazine, New York, September 1908, Vol. LXXVI, No. 5, pp. 641-650*. The one with Flyer II (1904) later.

Comment: @Federico, I included the illustration to make it clear that I refer to Flyer II of the Wright brothers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**What W. Wright describes in his two letters to G. A. Spratt is pure fiction, imaginary flights.**

Using the zero lift drag coefficient taken from the [lift and drag diagram of the Wright 1903 machine](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lift_and_Drag_for_Wright_1903_Flyer.gif) (a valid approximation as Flyer I and II were quite similar) and also the technical characteristics of Flyer II as it was before September 10, 1904, (without weights of steel added), I reached the conclusion (see the Mathcad worksheet below) that, for the interval of airspeeds ranging between 30 and 45 mph, the drag, when Lift = Weight, increased continuously.

As can be seen in the diagram, the thrust at constant power was always above the total drag till somewhere between 30 and 35 mph but it dropped below after that and in consequence the airplane could not have reached 45 mph.

In theory the plane had enough power to take off and fly without problems only below 35 mph. The story of Wilbur with the rapid acceleration of his apparatus after reaching 30 mph is just just imagination based on wrong beliefs.

[image: The Drag and Thrust of Flyer II]
The Drag and Thrust of Flyer II (1904). The induced drag formula was taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-induced_drag). I also took into account the fact the plane had two wings, one above the other.

Comment: the Wrights were very smart, practical people who made extremely accurate *observations* on the performance of their aircraft.  They would have no reason to engage in "fiction" as they were risking their lives.  What they were describing is consistent with lower induced drag at higher airspeeds.  Their issue may have been with prop *pitch*.  They had a wind tunnel, and could have tested *thrust* at various airspeeds.  As you properly mentioned, they also may have had airflow issues over the lower wing, rendering it ineffective at lower airspeeds.

Comment: For Flyer II, an airspeed of 40 mph is only possible with about a 30 hp engine and 45 mph with 40 hp. The 1904 motor of 17 hp was too weak even for 35 mph.

Comment: What the heck......?

Comment: Where do you get the 66% propeller efficiency ?

Comment: @MaximEck The propellers of Flyer I (the same as for Flyer II) were "remarkably efficient, converting 66 percent of the mechanical energy from the motor into thrust" (see: http://www.wright-brothers.org/Information_Desk/Just_the_Facts/Engines_&_Props/1903_Props.htm#:~:text=When%20the%20brothers%20finally%20did,from%20the%20motor%20into%20thrust.)

Comment: At what airspeed ? Fixed pitch propeller have a huge variation in efficiency relative to wind speed !! If it's 66% staying still that's pretty impressive yes and that efficency will go up to 80% easily when the aircraft is speeding up

Comment: @MaximEck The efficiency was 66% when the plane ran at an airspeed of 24 mph (see:https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.01006/?sp=6).

Comment: Does your mathcadding take into account the ground effect?

Answer (score 13):

Yes and in this case this is due to induced drag.

This drag can be derived with the lift and drag equations of a wing :

$$\textit{Lift} = \frac{1}{2} \rho C_L S V^2$$
$$\textit{Drag} = \frac{1}{2} \rho C_D S V^2$$

With decomposition on first order of the drag coefficient as follow $$C_D = C_{D_0}+k C_L^2$$

We get, $$D = \frac{1}{2} \rho (C_{D_0}+k C_L^2) S V^2 = \frac{1}{2} \rho C_{D_0} S V^2 + \frac{1}{2} \rho S \bigg(k\bigg(\frac{2L}{\rho SV^2}\bigg)^2\bigg)V^2$$

As you can see the second part called induced drag is decreasing with respect of $V^{-2}$. Therefore while flying slow the the faster you go the less drag you will have to overcome as you can see in the following picture. And at one point the other drag forces in the first term, namely pressure drag and friction drag will push back the drag to increase as $V^2$:

[image]

As you can see your assumption that the airplane drag increases with $v^2$ is not entirely valid. This works under the assumption of level flight, meaning that your lift remains constant and the induced drag of the wing is therefore only dependent on the air speed. As the wing efficiency decreases with AOA increasing, flying at slow speed and high AOA will generate more induced drag than flying faster with smaller AOA.

Stall of the propeller at low speed might be another explanation why the acceleration is slower. With fixed pitch, thin propeller blades you might enter stall region with to high AOA which will prevent you to have good acceleration at low speed. In the early days of VP props people used to run off the end of runways through trying to take off in coarse pitch. They propeller was stalled and only a small amount of power was transferred to thrust.

Comment: @MaximEck The plane was not capable of taking off itself in a calm only because the length of the rail was too short, and could not be extended for technical reasons. W. Wright says in one of the letters that it was difficult for the plane to reach more than 20 mph (in still air) while running on the rail but, with a headwind of 10 mph, the airspeed rose to 30 mph at take-off. In consequence the plane was able to reach an airspeed of 30 mph in a calm assuming the rail would have been long enough.

Comment: Okay I have seen design that had that flaw, but in this case it seems to implies that only the inuced drag is the consequence of this behaviour

Comment: @MaximEck well, their runway turned out to not be long enough, in either case.

Comment: I used your formula for the particular case of Flyer II (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Flyer_II) and I always get the minimum of the total drag before the interval 30 mph - 45 mph. Besides this, immediately after 30 mph the thrust gets quite close to the total drag and at 35 mph, or even less, the thrust equals the total drag. In other words, the descending part of the total drag is outside the interval 30 - 45 mph of interest.

Comment: How did you evaluate the constants $C_{D_0}$ and $k$?

Comment: @MaximEck the part about the propeller is very good reasoning, as for L/D, indused drag etc (I admit this is somewhat outside my competence), have you considered the fact that W bros were flying in ground effect? This will have major effects on the dynamics of flight.

Comment: To add to prevous, might it be so that flying in  ground effect "extends" or flattens the bottom part of the **backside of the power curve**? It seems to me the speed region in which W bros were struggling was relatively large.

Comment: Another factor could be that the engine produced more power at higher RPM, and flying faster unloaded the engine slightly, allowing it to run a little faster and reach it's power band. Admittedly, this is unlikely for the Wright Flyer, but it's a common issue with RC pylon racers running tuned pipes on 2-stroke engines.

Comment: @Jpe61 ground effect actually lower induced drag by decreasing downwash and wingtip vortices. It probably helped them to fly with an underpowered airplane.

Comment: This is what i thought. Without ground effect, and the propeller being stalled, they would have been way "deeper" in the backside of the power curve, travelling downwards. With correct technique and given enough altitude, they would have gotten extra speed by diving. Then again, placing the rails on the edge of a cliff might not have been so tempting with such an experimental craft. And it would have been cheating 

Comment: @MaximEck Cd0 (the zero lift drag coefficient) = 0.08 (see: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lift_and_Drag_for_Wright_1903_Flyer.gif). With the relations from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-induced_drag and knowing that the wingspan of Flyer II was 40 ft you can calculate k.

Comment: @RobertWerner I answered this question hopefully I know how to use the formulas... My problem is that I had a bit of time on myself, did the calculations and oops it might actually work.

Comment: It says here: https://www.uh.edu/engines/epi1867.htm that the W bros tested propellers with a scale model. I wonder how familiar they were with how airflow scales, I'm thinking reynolds number... Did they possibly get the calculations wrong because they used a scalel model for determining thrust? And possibly ended up using wrong prop profile?

Comment: @Simplex11 I quickly did the calculation: thrust drag equilibrium around 36mph and a minimal drag value around 28mph assuming perfect propeller efficiency. What we don't know is how this efficiency change with airspeed and ground effect performances. At this minimum drag value they could see this acceleration. But what we also know is that they claim their longest flight 1304 ft. in 39-1/2, that's around 22mph in average, below the written stall speed. So something is off for sure. The behavior I explained there is still valid, whether they measured speed correctly is up to you to decide ;)

Comment: "Longest flight 1304 ft. in 39-1/2" into a 10 mph wind?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, and it occurs with nearly every airplane there is.**

It is caused by **[lift-induced drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-induced_drag)**.

[image]

Lift is created by a wing deflecting airflow downward, itself being pushed upward as a result. (Newton's third law)

Lift-induced drag is the backward component of the resulting reaction force acting on a wing. Since at lower speed, the wing needs to be tilted up more to create the necessary lift from the tiny available airfow, the **total drag force created by the wing can increase - dramatically.**

The Concorde, for example, had a lift-to-drag ratio of 4:1 at takeoff, but 7:1 at Mach 2.

Induced drag follows the *inverse* of the drag equation you mentioned - it *decreases with the square of velocity*.

The drag referred to in your equation is **parasitic drag** which is created by air interacting with the airplane in useless ways, such as squashing against the nose, creating friction on the skin, etc.

Comment: But the concorde had a L/D of 12 at M0.95, so it's not always increasing

Comment: @MaximEck ah, that's probably parasitic drag

Comment: Parasitic, supersonic shock waves, there are plenty of reason but the concorde is not really the best example, as you have nose dropped during take off, and a wing designed to fly supersonic it has very different characteristics than an airliner. In most recent glider for example best glide ratio is reach close to stall speed, just before the inflection of the lift curve with AOA.

Comment: @MaximEck I disagree. The basic principle - Newton's third law - remains the same during both flight phases. The Concorde's wing allowed it to fly at very high AoA without stalling, *actually simplifying* comparison of induced drag at various AoAs (and thus speeds). Moreover, the existence of wave drag at Mach 2 actually serves to make the comparison even *more* meaningful.

Comment: You cannot explain lift and drag using Newton third law !!! Just saw your explanation of lift, it's much more complex than that and has more to do with pressure field than action-reaction. Considering the high AOA of the Concorde, it's just the working principle of the Delta wing. It's stalled but it still generate lift. Your leading edge creates a huge vortice on the upper side of the wing, reducing pressure and generating lift, but it has enormous drag, requiring the postcombustion used on the Concorde

Comment: @MaximEck Oh yes we can. Pressure is the **manifestation** of Newton's third law. Remember, pressure is *force/area*? Also, that vortex was what I was referring to. Also, why is it a stall? A stall, AFAIK, is when the slope of the lift curve is negative.

Comment: How do you explain low pressure on the succion side with Newton 3rd law? Try to calculate how much force is needed to deflect the air by changing its momentum, nowhere near the force required to fly the airplane. Depends on how you define stall, some says when lift decrease, other when lift to drag ratio dramatically increases or even when you have flow separation. The latter two are correct with high AOA delta wings. On traditional wings all 3 arise roughly at the same time

Comment: @MaximEck Would that suction exist if the air wasn't being *sucked*?

Comment: Sucked by what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113337/discussion-between-maximeck-and-abdullah).